# Effect of Event on Another

Tags: probability, data-analysis

I am having difficulty wrapping my mind around conceptualizing the impact of one event on another.

For the scope of this question, let's define the following:
Event A: An assault occurs;
Event B: A rival gang completes a drug sale in hostile turf.

Consider perfect data, such that these events can be ideally quantified and analyzed. The period of data used for the analysis is 6 months.

I wish to discover the impact of Event B on Event A; however, as opposed to a boolean occurred/didn't occur, I want to take into consideration the *number* of assaults that occurred during the scope of Event B (severity of impact).
Am I contaminating my question? Notably, (below) my formula fails to address the number of days in which assaults occurred.

From a transactional perspective, to determine a theoretical weighting of Event B upon A, I would assess the situation as follows:

$Days_T:$ Total number of days in the 6-month period

$Days_B:$ Total number of days on which a rival gang completes a drug sale in hostile turf in the 6 month period

$Assault_T:$ Total number of assaults in the 6-month period

$Assault_B:$ Total number of assaults on days in which a rival gang completed a drug sale in hostile turf in the 6 month period.

$(Assault_B \div Assault_T) \times (Days_T \div Days_B)$

Should I be using *total number of days on which assaults occurred* instead of the total number of days in the 6-month period?

Ideally, I am aiming to predict assaults based on a number of available precipitators, but I'm very much doubting my own logic at the moment.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: helluva examples they have at your college for an introductory probability course. I've never seen rival gangs and drug sales in this context before.

Comment: Ahh, perhaps I should have gone with _VC investments_ and _dinner dates_. It just didn't have quite the same... exotic-mathy-stuff ring to it.